# IIS 7.5 MVC4/.NET4.5 Nothing but the default page loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

... everything else (scripts, css, other pages) return a 404 error.  This works on my DEV machine under IIS Express so I'm assuming I've configured IIS 7.5 incorrectly, but nothing leaps out at me.  So all I get when navigating to the site is a couple lines of HTML, with no styling or javascript.  Looks like a web page out of the 90's.

I have:

- set up my own app pool for my application running integrated .NET 4
- ensured the web.config has `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` in the `system.webServer` element
- re-installed .NET 4.5
- installed the MVC4.0 runtimes to the GAC

What am I missing?

Comment: have you registered the version of .net you are using with the reg iis tool?

Comment: yes, that is what I meant by my third bullet.

Comment: Means your handler mappings are messed up. Try reverting to default under "Handler Mappings" in IIS for the selected site.

Comment: @dirt, this was ineffective.  The problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that my core project was set to use .NET4 instead of .NET4.5, which caused this condition.